# AppleScript to rename a file within an App

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write a script that will rename a file within an App. This way if an update happens, it will correct an issue. I have the following, but am not sure how correct it is:

```
on idle
    tell application "Finder"
        set msgbox to "/Applications/VideoHost.app/Contents/Resources/MsgBox.nib" exists
    end tell
    if msgbox = true then
        tell application "Finder"
            set the name of file "/Applications/VideoHost.app/Contents/Resources/MsgBox.nib" to
            "/Applications/VideoHost.app/Contents/Resources/No_MsgBox.nib"
        end tell
    end if
    return 60
end idle
```

I will add this to my Start Up items and choose the "Stay Open After Run" option

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
on idle
    set msgboxPath to "/Applications/VideoHost.app/Contents/Resources/MsgBox.nib"

    tell application "System Events"
        if exists file msgboxPath then set name of file msgboxPath to "No_MsgBox.nib"
    end tell

    return 60
end idle
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work... I don't know if it's because it asks for elevated privileges or not...

Comment: No Error... Just doesn't rename it.